# Is it possible to patch a crack in a toilet?

Tags: repair, toilet

We have a medicine cabinet placed above the toilet. Not the best place but not a lot of choice. Anyway, while fumbling for some Sudafed in the dark, I managed to knock a cough mixture bottle out of the cabinet.

**CRACK**

Takes a chunk about three inches long one wide out of the rim of the bowl, <strike>and I think caused a crack down the side as well.</strike> EDIT: definite cracks on the outside, can feel a slightly raised edge.

So, I know we need a new toilet but it will be awhile  till we can sort one. Is there  anything I can patch it with in the meantime. As it's the only toilet in the house.

EDIT: One thought was to duct tape the side,would hope that could a least hold it together for a little while.

Comment: If you go out, make sure you shut off the water to the toilet.  The crack will keep expanding no matter how you temporarily patch it and you do not want to come home to a flooded house.

Comment: @Jeff - If it's only the bowl that's cracked then it's only that water that will spill if it failed completely, but your's is still a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help, in the end we managed get a plumber at very short notice. So I didn't have to try drastic measures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try a marine grade epoxy (loctite makes such a product) to just seal the crack for a short time. If you still have the chunk that was broken off the marine grade epoxy should work but it's probably not going to look pretty. I've used it before and it mixes up to a rather ugly dark gray/black color and dries the same, but if you can live with the color difference it is VERY strong and waterproof. I used it to seal a leaky PVC pipe for a number of days until I had the time to fix it properly and not a drop of water came out.

EDIT: Found a link to the product [here](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xjv/R-100371825/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053)

Answer (score 0):

do not try to patch a toilet.  it wont work and when it does fail, someone will probably get badly cut, and absolutely guaranteed you will have a costly flood.  either way, it will cost more than a new toilet.

if you're broke, get a used one on craiglist, or from your local re-use it store.  or just ask a contractor if you can have one from his next bathroom renovation.