# What is a quick and temporary fix for a cracked toilet waste pipe?

Tags: plumbing, repair, toilet

Somehow the porcelain waste pipe of the toilet has cracked and has started leaking. We're about to replace the whole bathroom so I just need a quick fix. Will wrapping the crack in duck tape work?

Comment: Fortunately the inside drain of a toilet is not pressurized, so thick globs of plumbers putty will do the trick until you eventually replace the toilet, but PLEASE keep in mind this is a temporary fix.

Comment: You're talking about part of the toilet itself, not the underlying plumbing?

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1889/is-it-possible-to-patch-a-crack-in-a-toilet?rq=1

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo yes, it's the part of the toilet just before it attaches to the waste pipe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Epoxy putty, found in the plumbing repair section or adhesives section of your local big box store:

[image]

It's a two part compound that you work together like clay.  Blend a small amount, per instructions, then force it into the crack, ensuring it completely fills the crack.

Comment: Many thanks, hadn't even heard of the stuff before. Will try that.